# Random point generation for 2 dimension points with range from -5 to +5 in python

Tags: python, random, point

how can i create 5 random point for each x and y coordinate within certain range in python. I came across rand function but I was not able to find how to proceed further for 2dimension points.

Comment: Have you tried using it twice to generate an `x` and a `y` coordinate?

Comment: no i havenot tried so I should put the code rand.randomint(-5,+5) within loop which run twice?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function like this, to generalise the functionality a little:

```
import random

def random_point(dimension=2, min_c=-5, max_c=5):
    return [random.randint(min_c, max_c) for _ in range(dimension)]

print(random_point())
```

This will print a random 2-dimensional point in space as a list of coordinates, with coordinated between -5 and 5 inclusive.

To get the `x` and `y` separately, you could do:

```
x, y = random_point()
```

If you're absolutely sure you only need a 2-d point between -5 and 5, you could do this:

```
x, y = (random.randint(-5, 5) for _ in range(2))
```

But I'd recommend the first approach for being cleaner and more reusable.